# PySpark Dataframe: append to each value of a column a word

Tags: dataframe, pyspark

I would like to append to each value of a column in a pyspark dataframe a word( for example from a list of words). I though to just convert it to pandas framework because it is easier but I need to do it on pyspark. Any Ideas? Thank you :)

Comment: Please show what have you tried.

Answer (score 4):

you can do it easily with `concat` function:

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
for col in df.columns:
    df.withColumn(col, F.concat(F.col(col), F.lit("new_word"))
```